# Suppressing user defined function output?

Tags: c

Short version up top, long version down below.
Let's say I have a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>

int funcA();
void funcB();

int main(){
    funcA();
    funcB();
return 0;
}

int funcA(){
    int x=7;
    printf("this is the output of funcA()\n");
    return x;
} 

void funcB(){
    int y,z;
    y=funcA();        //this is me trying to store x from funcA() in y from funcB()
    z=y*5;
    printf("the output of funcB() is %d",z);
}
```

Here is the output of this little function:

```
this is the output of funcA()
this is the output of funcA()
the output of funcB() is 35
```

All I want is for it to say the out put of funcA() once and funcB() once, but when I try to use the return value of funcA() as a variable in funcB() it shows funcA()'s output again. How do I stop this? Thank you in advance, and thanks to the helpful user who helped me format this better.

LONG PART:
Here is the bit of my program that is causing me this grief:

```
float pcRRV(){                                  //calculate power consumption with rated resistor values
    int i;
    float pr=0,ptemp;                       //pr=power with rated values, ptemp=temporary power variable for for() loop
    for(i=0;i<=RMAX;i++){
            R=RRV[i];
            ptemp=(V*V)/R;                  //power= V^2/R
            pr=ptemp+pr;                    //add all power values (could also have added all resistors then calculated total power, either would require for() loop)
    }
    printf("Given the rated resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a %dV source, is %fW.\n",V,pr);
    puts("");
    return pr;                              //need power value for part D
}
float pcARV(){                                  //calculate power consumption with actual resistor values
    int i;
    float pa=0,ptemp;                       //same formate as previous function
    for(i=0;i<=RMAX;i++){
            A=ARV[i];
            ptemp=(V*V)/A;
            pa=ptemp+pa;
    }
    printf("Given the actual resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a %dV source, is %fW.\n",V,pa);
    puts("");
    return pa;
}

float powerpercentdif(){                        //calculate percent difference between two power consumption values
    float a,b;
    float powerdif,powerave,percentdif;
    a=pcRRV();                              //use return value of pcRRV() as variable
    b=pcARV();                              //use return value of pcARV() as variable
    powerdif=(a-b);
    powerave=(a+b)/2;
    percentdif=(powerdif/powerave)*100;
    printf("The percent difference between the power consumption given the rated values and given the actual values of the resistors is %f%%.\n",percentdif);
}
```

So I have these 3 user defined functions, pcRRV(), pcARV(), and powerpercentdif(). in my main function I call all 3 in the order that you see, and the output should be as follows:

```
Given the rated resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a 10V source, is 66.240997W.

Given the actual resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a 10V source, is 64.273056W.

The percent difference between the power consumption given the rated values and given the actual values of the resistors is 3.015677%.
```

But what actually happens is this:

```
Given the rated resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a 10V source, is 66.240997W.

Given the actual resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a 10V source, is 64.273056W.

Given the rated resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a 10V source, is 66.240997W.

Given the actual resistor values, the power consumed by the resistors, in series with a 10V source, is 64.273056W.

The percent difference between the power consumption given the rated values and given the actual values of the resistors is 3.015677%.
```

Now I don't want the output of the first two functions to be displayed twice. The easiest approach would be to not call the first two functions in main, but let their outputs be displayed when the 3rd function calls them. However, since this is for a class, one of the requirements is that the 3 functions I wrote must all be called in the main function to display their output, so I have to call all 3, but I don't want the output twice. Ultimately I'm wondering how to suppress the output of the 1st and 2nd functions when I assign them to variables in the 3rd function, because I just want to use their return values in that function, not have them display their full output. Thank you for the help in advance, and when I get a reply with a super simple answer I will be a combination of relieved/angry/depressed/happy. (I've been at this for a while) Thank you!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete  and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [edit] your question to do so. You refer to calling the functions from `main()` and issues with output, but the code you've provided does not include the code from `main()` at all so we can see what you're doing there. We can't possibly debug or troubleshoot code we cannot see.

Comment: I'll make it more reader friendly right now, sorry!

Comment: Have a function that calculates, and another function that prints.

Comment: @n.m. I just redid it so that I have a function that calculates and another that prints, but anytime I try to assign a variable to the function it prints it's output.

Comment: @Mr.F There is no way to call a function that prints things without letting it print things. That's why you should have a function that *only* calculates what is to be printed, and a *different* function that calls the first function to figure out the number to print, then prints it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. What you *can* do is make the function *not* print the result. You could move the printing part to another function, or put it directly in `main` (or whatever calls these functions) if you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int funcA();
void print_funcA();
int funcB();
void print_funcB();

int main(){
    print_funcA();
    print_funcB();
    return 0;
}

int funcA(){
    int x=7;
    return x;
}

void print_funcA() {
    printf("the output of funcA() is: %d\n", funcA());
}

int funcB(){
    int y,z;
    y=funcA();        //this is me trying to store x from funcA() in y from funcB()
    z=y*5;
    return z;
}

void print_funcB() {
    printf("the output of funcB() is: %d\n", funcB());
}
```

Comment: Perfect perfect perfect. Thank you so much. Just made this change and it works perfectly. Thanks to you and to n.m. for the help.

Comment: @Mr.F btw, I lied when I said "you can't". It would be more accurate to say "you shouldn't". It will only confuse you later, but it *is* possible to pass a parameter to the function telling it whether to print, or use a global variable.

Comment: That seems to be the strategy with any topic that can be lightly covered for basic use, but delves much deeper for more intricate usage. But for my application it definitely works fine. And I was just trying to avoid a lot of global variables over all. Thanks again.